Do not expand function parameters with nvim-cmp
I'm using nvim-cmp for completion. The documentation only says that I can accept a suggestion using the following command:
cmp.mapping.confirm { select = true },

My problem with this that it expands function parameters, which I find distracting, and worse, it can screw up my editing if I exit insert mode. I want it to do one thing, which is to insert the name of the function and do not insert any parameters or closing parenthesis or anything. Is it even possible?
